# Theorem 11 from General Topology by Kelley

Tags: general-topology

> *A family $\mathscr{B}$ of sets is a base for some topology for the set $X=\cup\{B:B\in \mathscr{B}\}$ if and only if for every two members $U$ and $V$ of $\mathscr{B}$ and each point $x$ in $U\cap V$ there is $W$ in $\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in W$ and $W\subset U \cap V$.*

I don't understand the beginning of the proof, in bold:

**Proof**

If $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for some topology, $U$ and $V$ are members of $\mathscr{B}$ and $x\in U \cap V$ then, **since $U \cap V$ is open, there is a member of $\mathscr{B}$ to which $x$ belongs and which is a subset of $U\cap V$**...

Is the intersection open because all subsets of topological space open?

I don't understand that if $U,V\in \mathscr{B}$, by what reason there exists $W\subset \mathscr{B}$ such that $W\subset U \cap V$.

*Edit*
I think I found the reason for $W\subset V\cap U$. It's from the definition of *base*.

> A family $\mathscr{B}$ of sets is a base for a topology $\tau$ if and only if $\mathscr{B}$ is a subfamily of $\tau$ and for each point $x$ of the space, **and each neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, there is a member $V$ of $\mathscr{B}$ s.t $x\in V\subset U$**.

So since in theorem $V \cap U$ is open, it is a neighbourhood of $\mathscr{B}$. So there is a subset $W\subset \mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in W\subset U\cap V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base for a topology is a collection of open subsets of the topological space, such that each open subset of the space may be expressed as the union of elements in the base. By axioms, $U\cap V$ is open, hence may be expressed as $U\cap V=\cup_{W\in\mathcal{A}}W$, for some subcollection $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{B}$. Moreover, $x\in \displaystyle\cup_{W\in\mathcal{A}}W$. Hence there exists $W\in\mathcal{B}$ containing $x$ and contained in $U\cap V$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topology (name it $\mathcal{T}$) then indeed $U \cap V \in \mathcal{T}$ too (as by (a) definition of a base, $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ (i.e. base sets are open in the topology they are a base for) and *topologies* are closed under finite intersections.
Also if $x \in U \cap V$ (which is in $\mathcal{T}$, this intersection is a union of members from $\mathcal{B}$ and in particular, there exists a base element $W$ that contains $x$ and sits inside $U \cap V$. This shows the necessity of that condition.